# How do I exit from a C# GraphQL subscription?

Tags: c#, graphql

I am subscribing to a GraphQL source using this code:

```
public override async Task RunAsync(RunMode mode, CancellationToken cancel)
{
    var consumer = new XYZConsumer(new GraphQLHttpClient(_options.Url, new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer()));
    var result = await consumer.GetAllXYZ();

    result.Subscribe(t =>
    {
        ****How_do_I_get_out_of_here?*****
...


public class XYZConsumer
{
    private IObservable<GraphQL.GraphQLResponse<SubscriptionApi>> subscriptionStream;
    private readonly IGraphQLClient _client;
    public XYZConsumer(IGraphQLClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<IObservable<GraphQL.GraphQLResponse<SubscriptionApi>>> GetAllXYZ()
    {
        var posSubscription = new GraphQL.GraphQLRequest

        {
            Query = @"subscription mquery..."
        };
        subscriptionStream = _client.CreateSubscriptionStream<SubscriptionApi>(posSubscription);
        return subscriptionStream;
    }
}
```

I have a couple of possibly related questions:

1. `GetAllXYZ` is highlighted by the compiler, with the message `This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator ...` Solutions I have found suggest I should be returing a task rather than `subscriptionStream` but I need to return that, so how can I change this?
2. I get stuck in the subscribe loop. How can I exit at `How_do_I_get_out_of_here?` when say 100 records have been read?

Comment: I think you will be able to implement following the docs here - https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/subscriptions , Instead of returning the stream you can return the Observable. For inspiration you can check here - https://github.com/baskarmib/CodeCamp2019/tree/master/aspnetcoreapp

Answer (score 0):

Add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` and `Take` limits it to e.g. 20 records:

```
result
   .Take(20)
   .Subscribe(t =>
```